# Ruby production server memory leak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, memory-leaks, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a production rails application server, the memory usage of rails worker process of which increases from ~300 MB to ~1.2GB in 3-4 days.

How can I debug this memory leak.
I am using rvm 2.2.2 and my application server is deployed in AWS:ElasticBeanstalk . I am using puma web server.

Please provide detailed answer.

Comment: which app server you are using?

Comment: I am using puma server.

Comment: By any chance, are you writing to S3 using the `aws-sdk` gem ?

Comment: yes, is there a possible memory leak in AWS library.

......
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem recently with ruby 2.2.2. I was writing to AWS S3 with the `aws-sdk` gem. I found the solution on [this issue on aws-sdk GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/785).

There is a memory leak in the `StringIO` class shipped with ruby 2.2.0 to 2.2.2. This class is used by `aws-sdk` when sending files to S3. This bug was [reported and fixed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10942) on 2.2.3.

Hopefully, upgrading to ruby 2.2.3 will fix your problem.

Comment: Hi haradwaith, tried this solution mentioned on github link you provided. Seems like it is working will have to monitor for a day to be sure.

Comment: Hi, this resolved the issue. Though this answer does not detail memory leak debugging in ruby, I am accepting this answer as the issue I faced is resolved.